# Submit form and then after the form is processed open a new page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'am trying to delete an entry/offer from the database and then get back to all the entries/offer overview page. I tried to do it with Javascript but unfortunately it does not open the overview page. It does the deleting but then stays on the page.

Is that the correct way anyways with javascript?

Here the two links Overview and delete Offer

```
<a id="overview" href="/mbm-kalkulation">Overview</a>
<form method="post" action="/?id='.$_REQUEST["id"].'" name="delOffer"><button type="submit">delete Offer</button>
```

Here the javascript which should click the overview page after the form got submitted.

```
((isset($_REQUEST["delOffer"]))?'
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery("a#overview").click();
            }, 1000);
        ':'')
```

Comment: php can send a location header, see here, first example

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Just make sure nothing is sent to the browser before the header!

Answer (score 1):

Normally such redirects are done using the header function from php. This is only possible, when the headers weren't already send. In this case you will have to use a JavaScript fallback. The code could look something like this:

```php
if (isset($_REQUEST["delOffer"])) {
  if (!headers_sent()) {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    header("Location: {$url}");
  } else {
    print "<script>window.location = '" . addslashes($url) . "';</script>";
  }

  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But any idea why my javascript code is not working? Shouldnt that work also? Also can you tell me why I just can't write the url in the action tag? If I do that somehow my offer gets not deleted.

Comment: Do you actually print your JS Snippet and is it inside of a script-tag? It could work, but I'm not completely sure if the browser actually navigates away, if you simulate a click event on a link.
You can not use the url in the action tab, since you have to make a request to your original url to tell the server that he has to delete something. Things are only executed when the corresponding file gets included